# Jquery Problem for stopping the loop

Tags: jquery, events, loops, onclick

I got this jquery code. And this is some kind of slideshow with fading effect. So it loops... this is the first code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function looptour(){
        $("#health").hide();
        $("#billing").hide();
        $("#pension").delay(6000).fadeOut(2000);
        $("#health").delay(6000).fadeIn(2000).delay(6000).fadeOut(2000);
        $("#billing").delay(14000).fadeIn(2000).delay(6000).fadeOut(2000);
        $("#pension").delay(14000).fadeIn(2000,looptour);
    }
    looptour();
});
```

My problem is to how to stop the loop that you saw on the first code onclick event? Then after clicking that event a new loop will proceed and so on...

Here's the new code,

```
$("#tournums").click(function(){
    function billingloop(){
        $("#health").hide();
        $("#pension").hide();
        $("#billing").delay(6000).fadeOut(2000);
        $("#pension").delay(6000).fadeIn(2000).delay(6000).fadeOut(2000);
        $("#health").delay(14000).fadeIn(2000).delay(6000).fadeOut(2000);
        $("#billing").delay(14000).fadeIn(2000,looptour);
    }
    billingloop();
});
```

Thank you so much jquery masters for helping me out with this problem of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is to use [`.clearQueue()`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) for this:

```
function stopLoop() {
    $("#pension").clearQueue();
    $("#health").clearQueue();
    $("#billing").clearQueue();
}

// snip //

$("#tournums").click(function(){
    stopLoop();

    function billingloop(){
        $("#health").hide();
        $("#pension").hide();
        $("#billing").delay(6000).fadeOut(2000);
        $("#pension").delay(6000).fadeIn(2000).delay(6000).fadeOut(2000);
        $("#health").delay(14000).fadeIn(2000).delay(6000).fadeOut(2000);
        $("#billing").delay(14000).fadeIn(2000,looptour);
    }
    billingloop();
});
```

Comment: I don't know.  Stick an `alert("whatever")` trace in there to see if your function is getting called at all.